# Configuring a Kamailio/OpenSER registrar/proxy for outbound SIP?

Tags: sip, voip, kamailio, openser, opensips

I've set up a Kamailio v4.0 SIP registrar and proxy for SIP over websockets, and everything is working fine except sending outbound messages or making outbound calls to a SIP address on a foreign domain. I can *receive* messages and calls from non-local SIP addresses, but not send any out.

I've tried to understand the documentation of various modules like `domain` and `outbound` and I'm still stumped. My configuration file is essentially identical to [this one](https://gist.github.com/jesusprubio/4066845).

This feels less like configuration and more like learning a new programming language. Any ideas on how to proceed?

edit: spotted the following in the log file:

```
INFO: rr [../outbound/api.h:49]: Failed to import bind_ob
INFO: rr [rr_mod.c:159]: outbound module not available
```

Recompiled with `STUN=1` and loaded `outbound.so` in config (is this barking up the wrong tree?). Now log says:

```
INFO: rr [rr_mod.c:156]: Bound rr module to outbound module
[...]
WARNING: <core> [msg_translator.c:2499]: TCP/TLS connection (id: 0) for WebSocket could not be found
ERROR: <core> [msg_translator.c:1725]: could not create Via header
ERROR: tm [t_fwd.c:435]: could not build request
```

Answer (score 1):

The logs suggest that no connection to the WebSocket client can be found. Kamailio cannot open a connection to a WebSocket (webrtc) softphone, if one does not exist, the SIP message cannot be delivered.

You can list active TCP connections using kamcmd tool:

```
kamcmd core.tcp_list
```

If you use WebSockets over TLS:

```
kamcmd tls.list
```

There is a config function that should be used in this case - **set_forward_no_connect()** - to avoid getting so far in processing.